# Error loading conftest.py due to missing field "lineno" from alias

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, conftest

I have a python/flask application with a test suite.

When I run

`coverage run -m pytest -s tests`

I get the following error:

`ImportError while loading conftest '/Users/abc/Documents/server/app/tests/conftest.py TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from alias`

My python version is 3.10.9
I am using macOS Moneterey 12.5 with Apple M1 Pro Chip. Coverage version is 5.0 with C extension. My pytest version is 7.1.1.

What I tried :

I encountered this problem on Python 3.8.9, and upgraded to 3.10.9. I also upgraded pytest to the latest version.

Then again I ran `coverage run -m pytest -s tests`

What I expected to happen:

I was expecting that the tests would start running.

What actually resulted:

`ImportError while loading conftest '/Users/abc/Documents/server/app/tests/conftest.py TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from alias`

Comment: That looks unusual.  Why are you using coverage 5.0 (from December 2019)? Can you link to your code? Do you have type aliases defined in your conftest.py?

Comment: @NedBatchelder I'm using whatever versions of packages are specified by the codebase of the company.

No there are no type aliases in conftest.py

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the fact that the installed version of **Python** does not match the installed version of the **pytest**, you should check and update your pytest and Python version .

> python --version

and for seeing pytest version use :

> pip list